# How to edit input file properties by using an android app?

Tags: java, android

i want to make an app which can add the file properties of a song file that the user inputs. Like adding the Album name of the song.. i am still a newbie in android app development...
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're looking to edit the [ID3 tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#Editing_ID3_tags) of an MP3 file (other formats, including MP4, usually have a different system for metadata).

Basically, you're going to want to:

- Open the MP3 file
- Read in the existing ID3 tags from the MP3 file
- Populate text views with the data
- When the user saves, write the new ID3 tags to the MP3 file.

It looks like there's [a fairly old library](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/) for dealing with id3 tags in Java, so you might even save yourself a lot of effort going that route.